# How to place code from library to my project without import 'library_name'

Tags: python, opencv, import, python-import

I want to use function cv2.getGaborKernel in my project. However, thus the project will be evaluated on a server, where only library available is numpy, I must provide code for this method with my own .py files. Is there any way to put library's fuction code into my project's files not to call 'import opencv' later?

```py
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Can you clone the project from git and install on it server? No need of internet to install this. Can you try this? It's not a best practice to copy paste the code without idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you put the code into the main script directly, or you use a second script and use

```
import secondscriptname
```

There is nothing else you can do to get your own Code into the script. Atleast if you can not use any other Libraries.

You can look up the script of cv2, and try to copy the function there to put it in youre Code.